# What is an alternative way of dragging objects in Xcode via VNC (from Windows)?

Tags: xcode, windows, macos, drag, vnc

Please note that I am ***not*** asking about Ctrl+Dragging. That is a different issue. I am asking about regular dragging, i.e. moving a text field around in my Main.storyboard file.

I can click on an object to bring up its little white boxes around the corners and sides, but I can neither drag around the object nor can I use the little white boxes to change the object's size.

I am using VNC Viewer on a Windows 10 platform and connecting to a Mac with version 10.11.6. On the Mac, I am using Xcode version 8.2.1 (8C1002).

Comment: you can use arrow keys

Comment: @Damirchi .....wow. It was that simple? Lol....thank you!